# Popups block bulk download of pdfs from website with wget

Tags: pdf, download, batch-processing, wget

I would like to download some free-to-download pdfs (copies of old newspaper) from this [website](http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg) of the Austrian National Library with `wget` using the `bash` script below:

```
for year in {14..57}; do
  for month in `seq -w 1 12`; do # -w for leading zero
    for day in `seq -w 1 31`; do
      wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd --no-check-certificate --content-disposition http://anno.onb.ac.at/pdfs/ONB_lzg_18$year$month$day.pdf
    done
  done
done
```

Aside of some newspaper issues not being available, I cannot download any issues even though they exist. I would get errors such as the one for the existing issue of June 30, 1814 for example:

```
http://anno.onb.ac.at/pdfs/ONB_lzg_18140630.pdf
Aufl"osen des Hostnamens anno.onb.ac.at (anno.onb.ac.at)... 193.170.112.230
Verbindungsaufbau zu anno.onb.ac.at (anno.onb.ac.at)|193.170.112.230|:80 ... verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, auf Antwort wird gewartet ... 404 Not Found
FEHLER 404: Not Found.
```

However, if you were to download the corresponding pdfs manually ([here](http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=18140630), see upper-right corner) you have to press "ok" in a pop-up acknowledgement. Once you did this, I can even download the issue via `wget` without a problem.

How can I tell wget to confirm via the command line the acknowledgements (the question you get once you want to download a pdf), see screenshot below? Is there a command in wget for that?

[image]

Comment: Just run a curl `curl 'http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno_pdf.pl?aid=lzg&datum=18140630' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Referer: http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=18140630' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed` In your script.

Comment: They might be using a IP based authentication to allow. When you hit the request once your IP gets whitelisted, probably for sometime and should allow you to download till the IP is whitlisted

Comment: Thank you, Tarun Lalwani, for your quick answer. Unfortunately, your suggestion did not function. I just copy 'n' pasted your code into a terminal and it just exists without doing anything.

Comment: Yeah it won't do anything but after that did you try to get the 404 URL you have in your question?

Comment: If I add your promising code before the one I posted above, I still get the mentioned error, unfortunately.

Comment: Okie let me check again, yesterday my IP got whitelisted the first time, so couldn't check

Comment: `lzg` is the newspaper type here?

Comment: Yes, it is the abbreviation for `Leipziger Zeitung`. How did you get whitelisted yesterday? Just by running your code above? I only get sort of whitelisted if I go to the website (link above) and click ok on the acknowledgement, then I can only download the pdf from that acknowledgement. For every other pdf, I have to again confirm each acknowledgement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170272/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-til-hund).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1. `lgz` newspaper is not available for all the dates
2. The PDF are not always generated and cached on the URL you used. You need to first run the other URL to make sure the PDF is generated

Below is the updated code that should work

```
#!/bin/bash

for year in {14..57}; do
  DATES=$(curl -sS "http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=18$year&zoom=33" |   gawk 'match($0, /datum=([^&]+)/, ary) {print ary[1]}' | xargs echo)

  for date in $DATES
  do 
      echo "Downloading for $date"

      curl "http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno_pdf.pl?aid=lzg&datum=$date" -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'DNT: 1' -H "Referer: http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=$date" -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed

      wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd --no-check-certificate --content-disposition http://anno.onb.ac.at/pdfs/ONB_lzg_$date.pdf
  done
done
```