# PDF download script downloads only some PDF and is slow

Tags: bash, pdf, download, wget

I would like to download some free-to-download pdfs (copies of an old newspaper) from [this](http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg) website of the Austrian National Library with `wget` using the bash script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#A script to download issues of the Leipziger Zeitung (1814-1857)

for year in {14..57}; do
  DATES=$(curl -sS "http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=18$year" | gawk 'match($0, /datum=([^&]+)/, ary) {print ary[1]}' | xargs echo)
  for date in $DATES; do
    echo "Downloading for $date"
    curl "http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno_pdf.pl?aid=lzg&datum=$date" -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'DNT: 1' -H "Referer: http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=$date" -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed
    wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd --no-check-certificate --content-disposition http://anno.onb.ac.at/pdfs/ONB_lzg_$date.pdf
  done
done
```

I figured out that the script just downloads the issues only from the Mondays and Saturdays (and if not available the Issues from Tuesday, respectively if available the Sunday issues) but not the rest during the week, see bash output below.

```
Downloading for 18140228
Downloading for 18140402
Downloading for 18140404
Downloading for 18140409
Downloading for 18140412
Downloading for 18140416
Downloading for 18140418
Downloading for 18140423
Downloading for 18140425
Downloading for 18140430
```

Back in the days not every days or months issues had been published or are available today. However, if you compare [this](http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=1814&zoom=33) calendar for 1814, for example April, you find that the script downloads only two issues of each week. It downloads the issues of April 4, 1814 and April 9, but does not download the available ones from April 5 to April 7. This is true for the other weeks in April 1814 and any other available month within the relevant time range between 1814 and 1857.

I am new to writing scripts and had help with the present one (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100023/popups-block-bulk-download-of-pdfs-from-website-with-wget) question here), so I do not know how to get it to download all available issues.

Also, I have measured with `time` that the curl command takes between 3 to 5 seconds to execute. Is there a way how to accelerate the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From browsing the page source for one of the annual index pages (e.g. http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=1814) it looks like the `match()` is only picking out the first `datum` on each line in the raw HTML.

Changing the `gawk` command to use `split()` instead picked out all the matches:

```
gawk 'split($0, t, /datum=[^&]+/, ary) {for (i=1; i in ary; i++) print substr(ary[i],7)}'
```

(As usual with `awk` and its descendants, there are many other ways to do this).

```
Downloading for 18140228
Downloading for 18140402
Downloading for 18140404
Downloading for 18140405
Downloading for 18140406
Downloading for 18140407
Downloading for 18140409
Downloading for 18140412
Downloading for 18140413
Downloading for 18140414
Downloading for 18140416
```

To speed things up, running the `wget` in the background seems to work well:

```
wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd --no-check-certificate --content-disposition http://anno.onb.ac.at/pdfs/ONB_lzg_$date.pdf &
```

- if not familiar, note the `&` on the end there.

I thought that would need a bit more work to constrain the number of downloads running at any one time, but in a test this resulted in about 10-12 downloads running together - from looking at `ps -ef | grep wget` on another session.

Comment: Awesome, d778899, this did the job!

Comment: Why does the `curl` actually takes so much time (3 to 5 s) to be executed?

Comment: It looks like most of that time is the response time from the ONB web server.  For example, using the Network inspector in Chrome (F12, then Network tab), http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno_pdf.pl?aid=lzg&datum=18140404 just timed at 4.66s.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the ones that were downloaded against what is available?  It appears that many issues are simply not available, notably Fridays and Sundays (perhaps not published for those days?), at least for the years I checked, and in some cases, whole months are missing.  Interesting project, by the way.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, enxio27. I should have stated clearer that there are months, and many days missing (either not available yet or never issued back in the days). However, the above script misses issues which are available, for example, Issue from April 3, 1814 to April 8, compare with the above output of downloaded issues and the month April 1814 [here](http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?aid=lzg&datum=1814&zoom=33).